# In Perl, checking a json decoded boolean value

Tags: perl, json, boolean

Decoded JSON booleans are objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $json_string = '{"boolean_field":true}';
my $decoded_json = from_json $json_string;

print Dumper $decoded_json;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'boolean_field' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' )
        };
```

From the [JSON.pm documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/JSON) I know about the following three methods:

- JSON::is_bool
- JSON::true
- JSON::false

However, for some silly reason I don't know how to determine if the value of 'boolean_field' in `$decoded_json` is true or false.

(Sorry for the very basic question; it's been driving me batty!)

Comment: Part of the confusion probably comes from Perl itself - **Perl does not have boolean types** in the language. It only has truthiness. When choosing a language for projects, this is one thing to consider, especially for consumers of JSON APIs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will be a truthy value in Perl. Just access it as normal.

```
print 'true' if $decoded_json->{'boolean_field'};
```

Comment: To expand on this, the JSON boolean objects use overloading to return `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`. The only reason the objects are needed is so you can tell the difference between a boolean and a an actual 0 or 1 if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! After investigation I accessed it as normal before in development code, but another issue masked the correct behavior, which lead me to try all manner of odd approaches (doh!)

Comment: @Quentin , I have a verification sub, where I need to check like this 

$boolean= 'true';

if( $decoded_json->{'boolean_field'} eq $boolean ){ # pass }. 

This condition fails, as $decoded_json->{'boolean_field'} returns 1. How do I evaluate it has string 'true' ?

Comment: @Subhash — If you have a new question then [you can ask one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) giving reference to this question if the context is useful.