# How to evaluate a json decoded boolean value as "true"

Tags: json, perl, boolean-expression

With reference to [In Perl, checking a json decoded boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792173/in-perl-checking-a-json-decoded-boolean-value) ,

I have a verification sub, where I need to check like this,

```
my $boolean = 'true';
my $json_string = '{"boolean_field":true}'; 
my $decoded_json = from_json $json_string;

&verify($boolean);

$boolean = 'false';
$json_string = '{"boolean_field":false}';
$decoded_json = from_json $json_string;

&verify($boolean);

sub verify {
  my $boolean = shift;
  if( $decoded_json->{'boolean_field'} eq $boolean ){
     # both are equal
  }
```

This if condition fails, as `$decoded_json->{'boolean_field'}` returns 1 or 0.

How do I evaluate `$decoded_json->{'boolean_field'}` as either string 'true' or 'false' ?

Work around I have now is

```
my $readBit = ($boolean =~ /false/ ) ? 0 : 1 ;
if( $decoded_json->{'boolean_field'} eq $readBit){
   # both are equal
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If it is `1` then it is not `"true"`.

Comment: Example JSON would help us answer. `'false'` is a string, it isn't "false" in a boolean logic sense. And that's the root of your problem I think.

Comment: @Quentin, made change in my original question. Where there is a single verification sub for both cases(true & false)

Comment: If you decoded the string with the JSON module or one of the same family, the boolean will be translated into an object that has overloading in place to return a truthy or falsey value. You just need to evaluate it directly. See the docs of JSON on cpan for boolean values.

Comment: The answer you have referenced says exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Boolean value, then you shouldn't be checking its value using a string comparison. You should only ever ask it if it is true or false. Your code should look more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $json_string = '{"boolean_field":true}';
my $decoded_json = from_json $json_string;

boolean_check($decoded_json->{boolean_field});

$json_string = '{"boolean_field":false}';
$decoded_json = from_json $json_string;

boolean_check($decoded_json->{boolean_field});

sub boolean_check {
  my $value = shift;

  if ($value) {
    say 'Value is true';
  } else {
    say 'Value is false';
  }
}
```

If you use Data::Dumper to look at `$decoded_json`, you'll see that `boolean_field` will contain an object which will return either a true or false value as appropriate.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'boolean_field' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

We don't need to use regex to find whether its true or false.
`0, undef, false` are false values, rest are true. Can you please try this solution?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $json_string = '{"boolean_field":0}';
# I tried with many possible combinations of boolean_field
# 0, false => returned false
# 1, 50 (Any value), true => returned true

my $decoded_json = from_json $json_string;
print 'true' if exists $decoded_json->{'boolean_field'};
# exists will check whether key boolean_field exists. It won't check for values
```

**Edit**: User needs to check key only, added `exists` in condition.

Comment: I need to get into if block, in both the cases, (true and false).

Comment: I do not want to check if key presents or not. I am verifying the value of `boolean_field`.

Comment: Not sure why you think `exists` is at all useful here. You need to check the truth of the value.

Comment: @DaveCross: On the above comment, he has written that **I need to get into if block, in both the cases, (true and false).**, that I think can be done from `exists`, however please correct me.

Comment: And then later he says **I do not want to check if key presents or not"". I'm not sure if the problem is with his understanding of the task, or his English :-)

Comment: His response was after around an hour, when I assumed that he wants to check for keys. I think English is his problem.

Comment: If I omit `exists` then my answer would be same as yours! Isn't it?